# Mongoose - Instantiate subSchema without parent

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, embedded-documents

Im trying to create a document and a subdocument separately.
Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('./streets');


const PlaceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  place1: String,
  streets: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'streetSchema'}]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('place', PlaceSchema);
```

SubSchema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const StreetSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    trafficLights: Number,
    shops: Number,
    busStops: Number,
  },
  { strict: false }
);

module.exports = StreetSchema;
```

Then I try to instantiate streets by itself:

```
const place = // ...get a certain place from DB;

const street = new Street({
  trafficLights: 1,
  shops: 2,
  busStops: 3,
});

place.streets.push(street)
```

and im getting

```
Street is not a constructor
```

How can I create instantiate the subSchema and push it into the 'streets' array?

PS - I also tried putting both of the Schemas in the same file, but couldnt reach the nested array (streets) without instantiating the entire "place" schema.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a model, please add this line at the end of your schema file

```js
mongoose.model('street', StreetSchema);
```

And import it wherever you need it

```js
const Street = mongoose.model('street');
```